# Add field to schema upon search query request in Solr

Tags: solr

Is it possible to add fields to the schema (managed or not, does not matter) at search query time?

Basically my Solr will receive search queries for fields that I cannot anticipate. If the query contains a field that is not in the schema, i get :

> "msg:undefined field"

I use Distance Function to sort results:

```
/select?q=city:Atlanta+_val_: dist(2,fieldX,fieldY,0,0)&fl=ticket_id,score&sort=score asc"
```

For example if fieldY is not in the schema, I would like Solr to give it a default value and not fail

Comment: Couldn't you use the [default function](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/function-queries.html#def-function) in that case?

Comment: This sounds like the right direction, but it still fails. So I would wrap each field in a "def" function, so: /select?q=city:Atlanta+_val_: dist(2,fieldX,def(fieldY,5),0,0)&fl=ticket_id,score&sort=score asc"
Or did I get it wrong? I still get "undefined field" for fieldY if it isnt in the schema. Very much appriciate your help!

Comment: I have a work-around now: If I get "undefined field" error I just insert a dummy document with the field and managed-schema mode will enter this field into the schema.